# More succinct way of getting a registry value as a string than (Get-ItemProperty $key $valueName)._VALUENAME_?

Tags: powershell, registry

The method for getting a value in a registry key from PowerShell is:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion CommonFilesDir
```

However, that command returns some extra properties I don't usually want:

```
CommonFilesDir : C:\Program Files\Common Files
PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
PSParentPath   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
PSChildName    : CurrentVersion
PSDrive        : HKLM
PSProvider     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

I just want the actual value, a string in this case. To do that I have to use the more verbose:

```
$commonFilesDir = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion CommonFilesDir).CommonFilesDir
```

Other than writing my own alias, is there a way of not writing the property name twice and getting a *string*?

I could run the following command, but it returns a PSObject:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion | Select CommonFilesDir
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm new to PowerShell, but it seems to work in PowerShell 2 and 3 if you leave out the registry value name in Get-ItemProperty, using the value name only as a property:

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).CommonFilesDir
```

or even shorter with the alias:

```
(gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).CommonFilesDir
```

No repetition of the value name, clean, and it can't get much more succinct.

Comment: That is more succunct!

Answer (score 4):

This is no less clunky, but there's no repetition if that's an itch you need to scratch:

```
(gi HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).GetValue("CommonFilesDir")
```

(personally I'd use `$env:commonprogramfiles` but that's besides the point.)

Comment: Unless you're looking to find other similar registry values, `$env:commonprogramfiles` is much less clunky, and returns the same value.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion | `
    Select CommonFilesDir
```

Comment: That is more succinct, but since it returns a PSObject, I need to use the dot notation later in my script. This does strip off the extra properties, but doesn't fully solve the problem.

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion | Select -expandproperty CommonFilesDir` should get you just the string.

Comment: @MikeShepard That should be its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to replicate an answer by Mike Shepard here (see comment under Musaab's answer) since he has not posted it himself. It is better because you don't have to put the name of the variable in your code.

So you can take this:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion | Select -expandproperty CommonFilesDir
```

And instead do this:

```
$w = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
$q = "CommonFilesDir"
Get-ItemProperty $w | Select -expandproperty $q
```